# How do I use charAt to check if the string doesn't start with a A-Z or a-z?

Tags: java

```
else if (!strEmail.toUppercase.charAt(0) < 'A' || !strEmail.toUppercase.charAt(0) > 'Z')
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Must start with A through Z or a through z");
        }
```

I tried doing that but I kept getting an error message. Should I just use charAt alone? Am I better off using indexOf to check if the string or email starts with a letter lower case or upper. I was thinking combining index and char, but I tried that, and it didn't work.

Comment: `...but I kept getting an error message.`  -- And what might that error message be?

Comment: If that code snippet is supposed to be Java, it will not compile. Your errors are syntactical, and don't have anything to do with `charAt()`. `.toUppercase.` should be `.toUpperCase().`

Comment: cannot find symbol

Comment: @Drizzy that's not the complete error message. The complete error message tells you **which** wymbold cann't be find, and where the problem is. Why don't you read it? Why don't you even think that reading it might be informative?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the 'or' to an 'and'- you have to be both lower than a A and greater than a Z. Remember- with `||`, only one condition has to be true for the whole statement to be true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` to check whether a `String` starts with an alphabet, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String pattern = "^[a-zA-Z].*$";
    System.out.println("abc".matches(pattern));
    System.out.println("Abc".matches(pattern));
    System.out.println("1ds".matches(pattern));
    System.out.println("1r1".matches(pattern));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be `toUpperCase()`; and I would use `substring` so I that I might test with a regular expression. Like,

```
if (!strEmail.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1).matches("[A-Z]")) {
    System.out.println("does not match");
}
```